# First Reference Leontief/Perfect Complements

Tags: reference-request, preferences, leontief

I googled a lot and I'm still to find:

**1. In which paper/book/reference do Leontief [production] functions make their first appearance?**

Similarly

**2. In which paper/book/reference do perfect complements/Leontief** *utilities* **make their first appearance?**